# Does VSTO applications work with MS Outlook connected to GSuite account?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, google-workspace

We have a custom VSTO Add in build for MS Outlook. But one of our clients have a MS Outlook as frontend that is connect to GSuite (Google Suite Sync) as the backend. Will a normal VSTO addin work in this scenario ?

We couldnt setup a GSuite hence asking.

Comment: I've written VSTO add-ins that worked regardless of whether the user was connected to Exchange, IMAP or POP3, so it is possible. You just need to make sure that the add-in doesn't rely on Exchange-specific functionality. Sender/recipient addresses will likely be SMTP instead of X400, and you may not be able to look up contacts on the server.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that the GSuite message store provider is buggy, so you are almost guaranteed to run into problems.